# How to clear Windows Server 2019 DNS suffix search list

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have a Server 2019 which should be with a static IP address. By mistake a DHCP address was assigned to it once during installation and the DHCP also has set the DNS suffix search list.

When running `ipconfig /all` I see nycab in the DNS suffix list and it causes issues with some applications I have. Comparing to other servers who did not get a DHCP address when installing there the DNS suffix is empty.

```
    Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : nycab

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : nycab
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::908a:a2d3:4eba:8092%2(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.128.146(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::92ec:77ff:fe0d:efed%2
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 100666409
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-29-31-92-9C-00-0C-29-AE-C4-5A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxx
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix Search List :
                                       nycab
```

I have tried resetting the network, running various powershell commands and even resetting the whole TCP stack but nothing seems to clear this nycab value.

If I set in the NIC a specific value in the DNS suffix that value is displayed in ipconfig but when clearing it the value reverts back to nycab.

Short of re-installing windows, how can I clear the DNS suffix? I searched the entire registry and it does not appear anywhere

Comment: a similar question could be found on https://superuser.com/questions/1507445/delete-and-add-entries-to-dns-suffixes maybe it helps

Comment: I tried running the command in the accepted answer there to clear the global cache ``` Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting -SuffixSearchList @("") ``` it did not help

Comment: and did you verified the windows settings way? - ehm update, i see  vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter -could it be that you running a virtual appliance and fetch from there the dns suffix?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am running in a VM under ESXi but I have no idea and do not think the suffix comes from the host as the host was up with a static IP way before the DHCP was running (for the brief time it did run)

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out in my case that my firewall also had a DHCPv6 running and that it publishes the domain (DNS suffix) of the domain it belongs to via multicasts and that windows was getting the info using one of these multicasts. The windows install itself did not contain any DNS suffix and that is why all the clear methods I tried did not work. in my case it was a setting in the firewall DHCPv6 named "Provide DNS configuration via radvd"